# Spring Inject boolean value from property file using XML is always false

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am trying to inject boolean property from property file. the value of the attribute is alway `false`

the property

```
use.virtual.wallet=true
```

The xml configuration

```
<bean id="proxyUtil" class="com.util.ProxyServiceUtility">
    <property name="useVirtualWallet" value="${use.virtual.wallet}" />
</bean>
```

the bean

```
public class ProxyServiceUtility {

    private boolean useVirtualWallet;

    public void setUseVirtualWallet(boolean useVirtualWallet) {
        this.useVirtualWallet = useVirtualWallet;
    }

    public boolean isUseVirtualWallet() {
        return useVirtualWallet;
    }
}
```

`useVirtualWallet` is alway false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem fixed using this workaround, instead of injecting `boolean`, I injected `String` and then converted that `String` to `boolean` on the setter

```
public void setUseVirtualWallet(String useVirtualWallet) {
    this.useVirtualWallet =  Boolean.parseBoolean(useVirtualWallet);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to **load your properties file** into Spring context using [**PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer**](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer).

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations" value="classpath:com/foo/jdbc.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I already do that, and i have a lot of other properties loaded  correctly, the only problem is regarding the boolean one

Answer (score 0):

Another variant

```
<beans 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:com/foo/jdbc.properties"/>
    ...

<beans>
```